# stop executing rest of code when throw exception java

Tags: java, exception

so suppose i ve three java class A,B and C (not in actual java syntax) see below, i have some line of code in `class B` which i dont wana execute when exception occurred in `class C` is there any way to manage this condition ?

**A.java**

```
class A{

     method a() {
       try{
         //calling method b
         B bObj= new B();
         bObj.b();
      }catch{

      }
     }


    public static void main(String arg[]){

          a();
     }


}
```

**B.java**

```
class B {

  method b()throws Exception {
    //calling method c
       C cObj = new C();
        cObj.c();
       /// here is some line of code
       // which i dont wana execute when exception occurred in method c
  }
}
```

**C.java**

```
class C {
metho c(){
       try {
          //database connection
          // executing query
       }catch{
            // closing connection
       }
} // end of method c

}
```

Comment: Have `c` store the exception and have `b` check if it's set or not.

Comment: i cant understand what you have written, can you write it more clearly ?

Comment: In your `C` class method, you catch an exception. Assuming that's the exception that you want to watch it for in `B`'s method, just store it in an `Exception` field in `C`. Before executing the code in `B`, check if that field is `null`. If it is, execute the method. If it isn't, don't execute the method.

Comment: can you write some demo code ?

Comment: After you catch exception, rethrow the same in methodC(). This exception will be thrown to caller( ie methodB()) and methodB() will stop executing the remaining code.

Comment: thanks alot man for this, currently i am using `update` query in `method c` so i am returning updated record count to `method b()` where i use `if(rowCount !=0){//execute code}`